# Pair Certificate Enrollment Request key and X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I'm migrating a tool that creates Certificate Enrollment Request (certmgr.msc) that prompts a security dialog to assign it a password, then send that request to the CA and later the CA sends back a Base 64 encoded certificate. Everything is fine.

Now, that i have that b64string, i can convert it to a certificate using

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b64string);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```

the thing is that i need to install that certificate in CurrentUser/Personal store to sign transactions, but i can't because the private key is not within the installed certificate.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

I think i must set the password withing the X509Certificate2 constructor, but how could i get that password? Or how could i pair the certificate request and the installed certificate?

I have some old C code that uses XEnroll i think, that does what i want in 1 line:

```
hr = m_pXEnroll->raw_acceptPKCS7( PKCS7 );
```

What i'm doing wrong? Maybe my focus is incorrect

Comment: To finish Windows certificate enrollment, you can use `IX509Enrollment.InstallResponse` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nf-certenroll-ix509enrollment-installresponse. XEnroll library is gone since Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008, so any example that uses XEnroll won't work anymore.

Comment: @Crypt32 i would like to make your response as the topic answer, but for completeness, i'll answer it myself with more detail. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made this up using CertEnrollLib.

As @Crypt32 pointed, it is just as easy as IX509Enrollment.InstallResponse(...)

This is my code:

```
CX509Enrollment objEnroll = new CX509EnrollmentClass();
objEnroll.Initialize(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser);
objEnroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowNone, pkcs7, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, null);
```

In my case, for this code to work i have to have a Certificate Enrollment Request, that i generated using the same lib. I'll post the link only cause it's not directly related to this topic.

https://www.sysadmins.lv/retired-msft-blogs/alejacma/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-csharp.aspx

I don't know if there is a more pure C# way of doing this in the framework version i'm using (4.0), but this worked for me.